# VBA - Excel - Automation Error Unspecified Error

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation, unspecified

So I ran into a slight stumbling block and hopefully here someone can help me.  In short, I need to visit a string of webpages (the list of the names on each page are already input, that code works fine).  As my code visits each page, I need to pull back information.  Unfortunately, there's a problem - it can't even make it through the "A" list before I get "Automation Error Unspecified Error" and it's never at the same spot.

I've tried the "normal" steps to fix this.  I've installed the VB 6 Controls and I've unregistered and re-registered mscomctl.ocx, and including On Error Resume Next (which doesn't do anything).

It usually reaches over 100 cases before it dies (randomly as I said earlier). And AFTER the error pops up, when I try to re-run it (with or without changes) and it errors on the first one.  If I restart my computer it will let me try again (for whatever reason) but it still doesn't finish.

Is the code too complex and I need to reduce it?  I can probably find a way to make it only run for each letter at a time (run all A's, then do B's, etc) but I still can't even get it to complete the letter A.

I noticed in another thread someone had suggested instead of using IE to swap to xmlhttp - is that a fix for this?  Is the problem that this script is too long?  What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub Lookup()
Range("AI1").Value = "Unique ID"
Range("AJ1").Value = "Name"
Range("AK1").Value = "Birth Year"
Range("AL1").Value = "Title"
Range("AM1").Value = "State"
Range("AN1").Value = "Position"
Range("AO1").Value = "Country"
Range("AP1").Value = "Appointed"
Range("AQ1").Value = "Credentials"
Range("AR1").Value = "Terminations"
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 26
    If i = 24 Then
        Range("X:X").End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Else
    Dim ic As String
    ic = LCase(ConvertToLetter(i))
    Range(ic & "5000").End(xlUp).Select
    Dim J As Integer
    J = ActiveCell.Row
    Dim k As Integer
    For k = 2 To J
        Range(ic & k).Select
        Dim Lookup As String
        Lookup = ActiveCell.Value
        Dim IE As Variant
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = False
        IE.navigate "http://history.state.gov/departmenthistory/people/" & Lookup
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Dim Italics As Integer
        Italics = 0
        Dim EachA As Integer
        For EachA = 64 To 100
            Dim Position As String
            Position = Doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(EachA).innerText
            If Position = "Home" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                Dim NameBY As String
                NameBY = Doc.getElementsByTagName("h2")(1).innerText
                Dim TitleST As String
                TitleST = Doc.getElementsByTagName("p")(1).innerText
                Range("AJ" & "90000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = NameBY
                TitleState = Split(TitleST, vbLf)
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TitleState(0)
                On Error GoTo 1037
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = TitleState(1)
                On Error GoTo 1037
1037
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = Position
                Dim EachLi As Integer
                EachLi = EachA - 1
                If Doc.getElementsByTagName("li").Item(EachLi + Italics).innerHTML Like "<em>*" Then
                    Italics = Italics + 1
                Else
                End If
                Dim JobList As String
                JobList = Doc.getElementsByTagName("li")(EachLi + Italics).innerText
                Dim Job() As String
                Job() = Split(JobList, vbLf)
                Dim JCount As Integer
                For JCount = LBound(Job) To UBound(Job)
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                    ActiveCell.Value = Job(JCount)
                Next JCount
            End If
        Next EachA
    Next k
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: xmlhttp request may be more reliable and should be faster. Not sure if it will resolve this issue. Difficult to pinpoint a problem if it's happening in various places. One thing I notice is that you're continually creating new IE objects inside the loop, and you're never destroying them or setting to `Nothing`. Might help simply to create one IE object initially, and use that same object to navigate inside the loop. It's pointless, expensive, and possibly a source of error to be creating 100+ instances of IE.

Comment: `Dim IE as Object` and `If IE Is Nothing Then Set IE = CreateObject(...`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  It actually was just the number of IE browsers - I thought by turning off Visible they weren't in "existence" so to speak.  Apparently my browser was crashing and it wouldn't restart because of it (hence the restarts refreshing it)!

Comment: I'll put this down as an answer, if you don't mind to please accept it; that way if others have similar problems, they may benefit from this.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you're continually creating new IE objects inside the loop, and you're never destroying them or setting to `Nothing`.  It's pointless, expensive, and possibly a source of error to be creating 100+ instances of IE.

I think it will probably help to create a single instance of IE initially, and then use that same object inside the loop to navigate the desired URLs.

So instead of this:

```
Dim IE As Variant
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Do this:

```
Dim IE as Object
If IE Is Nothing Then Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Comment: I did tweak it a little bit, using 
    
        Dim ShellWins As ShellWindows
        Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        Set ShellWins = New ShellWindows
        If ShellWins.Count > 0 Then
            Set IE = ShellWins.Item(0)
        Else
            Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
            IE.Visible = True
        End If
        IE.navigate "http://history.state.gov/departmenthistory/people/by-name/" & Letter
    
and adding     Set ShellWins = Nothing     and     Set IE = Nothing     after finishing with all my scripts.  Thank you so much!